# Cypher: Graph a nodes's connections 3 deep

Tags: neo4j, cypher

given a node, I want to use D3 to graph it, and it's neighborhood 3 deep.

The best strategy I can come up with is:

```
Query1:  MATCH (n)-[r]-(m) WHERE id(n) IN [501] RETURN n, r, m
```

Then from the results, in my app, collect all of m's id's, put those new id's in the IN clause (remove the ones I've already done), and repeat the query.

```
Query2:  MATCH (n)-[r]-(m) WHERE id(n) IN [502,511,1111] RETURN n, r, m
Query3:  MATCH (n)-[r]-(m) WHERE id(n) IN [512,519,1116,1130] RETURN n, r, m
```

Note: we don't know the id's of the 2nd query till after the 1st, etc.

But this means running 3 query's, and lost of IO shuffling.

Is there a better better way to do this?  I feel like I'm doing too much work in my app, when it should be done in cypher.  I looked in the D3 examples, but didn't see this kind of query.

Thanks!

Mike

Comment: Can you clarify what you are doing 3 times? Also, shouldn't that add up to 4 queries in total?

Comment: Does that help?  The IN clause keeps changing with the next level of nodes. Is there a way to do this on one query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the answers, they didn't work out for me.

I did this:

Set `idsTodo` to the initial node.

Then ran this:

```
MATCH (n)-[r]->(m) WHERE id(n) IN {idsTodo} RETURN n, r, m
```

Added `idsTodo` to `idsDone`
Then added m.ids to a `idsTodo`, then subtracted `idsDone`

Then ran the query again, repeating 2 more times.

By the end, I had every node and it's relationships.

Answer (score 1):

You can run following query or similar, but the concept should be easy to understand:

```
MATCH (n)-[r*1..3]-(m) WHERE id(n) IN [501] RETURN n, r, m
```

Where `*1..3` means match from 1 to 3 relationships away from the n node

This way it is only a single query and should be significantly faster then running three separate queries

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
MATCH (n)-[r]-(m)-[s]-(o) WHERE id(n) IN [501] RETURN n, r, m, s, o
```

Comment: Maybe.  I assumed this wouldn't work if  (a)--(b) didn't have any other nodes attached.

Comment: `MATCH (a)-[a1]-(b)-[b1*0..1]-(c)-[c1*0..1]-(d) WHERE id(a) IN [501] RETURN a,a1,b,b1,c,c1,d` is interesting, but there is alot of redundant data.  I don't need `(a)-[a1]-(b)-[b1]` for every result.  I just want `(c)-[c1]-(d)` for most of these.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

```
MATCH (n)-[r1]-(m1)-[r2]-(m2)-[r3]-(m3)
WHERE ID(n) = 501 AND
  ID(m2) IN [502,511,1111] AND
  ID(m3) IN [512,519,1116,1130]
RETURN n, r1, m1, r2, m2, r3, m3;
```

Comment: Hi cybersam, no that doesn't do it.  I won't know the Id's in the 2nd and 3rd queries till I've done the 1st query.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just combine all 3:

```
MATCH (n)-[r]-(m) 
WHERE id(n) IN [501]
WITH m 
MATCH (m)-[s]-(o)
WITH o
MATCH (o)-[t]-(p)
RETURN o,t,p
```

The difference between this and the other answers is that this will revisit relationships especially because there is no direction specified, if that's what you want.

Comment: Hi @Luanne, thanks.  I did some testing with this.  `RETURN DISTINCT o,t,p` cuts the number of rows returned.  It also returns "duplicate paths" e.g. "o,t,p" and "p,t,o".  Best answer so far.

Comment: (like you said in your answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

How about this: with `"resultDataContents":["graph"]`

```
MATCH path = (n)-[*..3]-(m)
WHERE id(n) IN [501] 
RETURN path
```

or if you want to save bandwidth

```
MATCH path = (n)-[*..3]-(m)
WHERE id(n) IN [501] 
RETURN [x in nodes(path) | id(x)] as node_ids, [x in rels(path) | id(x)] as rel_ids
```